# subprocess.call vs os.system python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, os.system

First time questioning here:

I have a need to map a network drive in windows.  The location is an internal sharepoint document library.

In the cmd window:

```
net use g: http://na.com/DMP/DMP/programming/
```

is successfull --> the command completed succeffuly

```
os.system('"net use k: http://na.com/DMP/DMP/programming/"')
```

is also successful.

However i would like to use subprocess.call in the event that the drive is already mapped - i would like to try another drive

```
call(["net", "use", ":q", '"http://na.com/DMP/DMP/programming/"'])
```

This fails with "System error 67 has occured. The network name cannot be found"
I have tried many options for the last list item with no luck.

Any idea what I can stuff in there to have this complete successfully or a different method to map drives.

Comment: Also, why are you putting `"` around the URL in the `subprocess` call, when you didn't do so in the `system` call (and `cmd` command line)? You're asking it to open the URL `"http://na.com/DMP/DMP/programming/"` instead of the URL `http://na.com/DMP/DMP/programming/`. I have no idea what this will do, but it's not hard to imagine it will treat it as, say, a relative path starting with `"http:`, or as a URL with protocol `"http`.

Comment: The OP has quoted the `os.system` call twice as well @abarnert; it's obviously not an identical situation, so the effect may be different, but it's equally confusing.

Comment: @Ben: You're right! Obviously the effect _is_ different, considering that one worked and the other didn't, but yeah, they're both confusing, and I'd hate to have to actually figure out (based on the arcane and half-documented quoting rules in various bits of Windows) _why_ one worked and not the other…

Comment: One more thing: As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#converting-an-argument-sequence-to-a-string-on-windows) say, "On Windows, an args sequence is converted to a string that can be parsed using the following rules". On Unix, you pretty much always want a sequence instead of a string—but on Windows, if you have already have a command line that works as a string, just use it as a string.

Comment: I've just also noticed that you're first command in the cmd window tries to use the **g** drive whereas the others are k: and q: (sort of). Are you 100% certain that these aren't already in use by other network shares? It might be wiser, before adding a share, to `net use k: /d`, for instance, though this relies on there being no open connections to k: on the box that you're running this from.

Comment: @Ben: I don't think `net use` will ever return an error 67 in that case… but since MSDN doesn't document the error codes for most of their tools, or give out the source code, and I don't have access to every version of Windows ever, I can't guarantee that… So yeah, it was probably worth bringing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two problems in your code:

```
call(["net", "use", ":q", '"http://na.com/DMP/DMP/programming/"'])
```

First, you've got `":q"` where you meant `"q:"`. This might cause the `net` command to interpret `:q` as your network location instead of your target drive, which could cause an error 67.

Second, you've got an extra set of quotes around the URL: `'"http://na.com/DMP/DMP/programming/"'` where you should be using `'http://na.com/DMP/DMP/programming/'`. When `subprocess` builds the string to pass to `CreateProcess`, it already quotes each of your parameters. So, if you quote them yourself, you end up double-quoting the parameters. There are some cases where this is actually not possible in Windows, so you end up with garbage, but I don't think that's the case here. You will successfully get this quoted string to `net`, telling it that you want to open either a relative path starting with `"http:` or a URL with protocol `"http`, or something like that. Whatever it is, it's not a usable network location, which most likely will cause an error 67.

As Ben pointed out, your `system` call has a similar problem—you put an extra pair of quotes around the entire string. If you really wanted to figure it out, there probably is some reason that this worked… but I don't think you want to figure it out. Just take it as "I did the wrong thing, but I got lucky", and don't do it that way in the future.

Finally, as [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#converting-an-argument-sequence-to-a-string-on-windows) says:

> On Windows, an args sequence is converted to a string that can be parsed

This means that, if you already have a working command line for Windows, you're better off just using it as a string, than trying to break it down into a sequence for `subprocess` to reassemble.

(Keep in mind that this is only true for Windows! On other platforms, instead of building a command line string to pass to a function in the [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) family, `subprocess` builds an array of strings to pass to a function in the `exec` family.)

So, just do this:

```
call("net use g: http://na.com/DMP/DMP/programming/")
```

Comment: the correction to g: yielded success - i learned alot and am now using  call("net use g: http://na.com/DMP/DMP/programming/")